# ¿Como ordenar el minimo de cada columna-fila?

Tags: python

Tengo que optimizar el tiempo de una maquina en cierta tarea, el archivo lee la matrix de un archivo csv o txt, en el cual encontre el más minimo de cada columna, pero ahora tengo que comparar los minimos de cada columna y acomodar cada uno en su respectiva tarea. Ejemplo con codigo ->

```
import csv
import numpy as geek

results = []

with open('INSTANCES/M1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
  #change contents to float
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) 
  #Each row is in a list
  for row in csv_reader:
    results.append(row)
print("\nDirecto del archivo CSV: " + str(results) + "\n")

intResults = []
matrix=[]
minFila =1000
newMF=1000
z = []
g=[]

for i in range(0, len(results)):
  intResults.append([])
for i in range(0, len(results)):
  for j in range(0, len(results[i])):
    intResults[i].append(int(results[i][j]))
matrix.append(geek.asarray(intResults))
#print(f"\n {matrix}")

for a in matrix:
    z = geek.array(a)
print(f"{z}\n")


for m in range(0, len(z)):
  for n in range(0, len(z[m])):
    if z[m][n]<minFila:
      minFila = z[m][n]

  g.append(minFila)
  minFila = 10000


#position of each lowest value
b = geek.argwhere(z<=g[:])
print(f"La posicion de los valores más minimos son: {b}\n")
print(f"Los valores de las posiciones con valores más minimos son: {g}")
```

La matriz leida del archivo es:

```
[[ 77  17  41  42]
 [ 79  66  28  26]
 [100  21  75  24]
 [ 87  32  41  80]]
```

Los valores y posiciones de los más minimos encontrados son:

```
 [[0 1]
 [1 3]
 [2 1]
 [2 3]]
[17, 26, 21, 32]
```

El objetivo es tener cambiar de posicion los demas valores de la matriz conforme a cada maquina se le asigne su tarea, no se debe repetir su fila y columna si una maquina ya tiene una tarea.
Las posiciones y los valores del resultado final deberian de ser:

```
[[0,1]
[1,2] 
[2,3] 
[3,0]]
[17, 28, 24, 87]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo he entendido bien, lo que buscas es obtener los valores mínimos de la matriz de forma que éstos no compartan fila o columna.

No se me ocurre una forma totalmente vectorizada para hacer esto, pero podrías hacer algo como:

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.array(
    [[ 77,  17,  41,  42],
     [ 79,  66,  28,  26],
     [100,  21,  75,  24],
     [ 87,  32,  41,  80]]
)

nmins = min(arr.shape)
indices = np.full(fill_value=-1, shape=(nmins, 2), dtype=int)
aux = zip(*np.unravel_index(np.argsort(arr, axis=None), arr.shape))

idx = 0
for x, y in aux:
    if x not in indices[:, 0] and y not in indices[:, 1]:
        indices[idx] = x, y
        if idx == nmins:
            break
        idx += 1

indices = indices[indices[:,0].argsort()]
valores = arr[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]]
```

> ```
> >>> indices
>
> array([[0, 1],
>        [1, 2],
>        [2, 3],
>        [3, 0]])
>
> >>> valores
>
> array([17, 28, 24, 87])
> ```

La idea es servirse de `numpy.argsort` para obtener los índices de los elementos ordenados de menor a mayor. Teniendo esto, vamos recorriendo los índices y nos quedamos con aquellos que  no compartan fila o columna con los previamente seleccionados.

Lo de hacer `indices[indices[:,0].argsort()]` viene solo motivado porque aparentemente quieres ordenar los índices en función de la fila, dado que el orden natural de éste sería:

> ```
> [[0 1]
>  [2 3]
>  [1 2]
>  [3 0]]
>
> [17, 24, 28, 87]
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Capaz no me explique muy bien en mi problema pero si, esa era la idea como tu escribiste el codigo, ahora lo implementare para que el codigo pueda leer valores de una mateiz desde una archivo csv o txt.

Comment: @Axel no lo he agregado porque no se exactamente la estructura de tu archivo, pero si es un csv en principio puedes cargarlo usando NumPy directamente con [numpy.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: Ya lo agregue al codigo y termine de verificarlo por si algo que no saliera bien, es que el programa tiene que leer matrices de 200x200 en adelante para lo que hara despues, gracias!